# githook - get branchname on a new repo

Tags: bash, git, githooks

I'm writing a `prepare-commit-msg` hook which appends the branch name to the commit msg. I m using this line to get the branch name

```
  local current_branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
```

The problem is that if no prior commit exists (when the repo was just initizalised) the command fails with the following error message

```
git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
HEAD
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
```

Is there some better way to get at the branch name, or to suppress the warning / error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
```

See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-symbolic-ref

Answer (score 0):

This is such a rare rare case, it's barely worth worrying about surely. You could just add a default, and suppress the error

```
$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD 2>/dev/null || echo "default branch")
```